# displaying a javascript-generated div in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

The following code shows what I expect in Firefox and Chrome:
a small white square in a big green rectangle.
I don't see the small square in IE7.
How can I make it appear?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function start()
{
    var g_Div = document.getElementById("bigdiv");
    var littleDiv = document.createElement('div');
    littleDiv.setAttribute('style', 
        'position:absolute;'+
        'left:300px;'+
        'top:300px;'+
        'width:5px;'+
        'height:5px;'+
        'clip:rect(0pt,5px,5px,0pt);'+
        'background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);');
    g_Div.appendChild(littleDiv);
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div 
    id="bigdiv" 
    style="border: 1px solid ; margin: auto; height: 600px; width: 800px; background-color: green;" 
    >   
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
start();
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want, and should work across the major browsers:

```
function start()
{
    var g_Div = document.getElementById("bigdiv");
    var littleDiv = document.createElement('div');
    littleDiv.style.background = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
    littleDiv.style.width = '5px';
    littleDiv.style.height = '5px';
    littleDiv.style.left = '300px';
    littleDiv.style.top = '300px';
    littleDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    g_Div.appendChild(littleDiv);
}
```

Comment: Works great!!
(except the black border that I don't want, but easy to remove)

Comment: Ha, oops. I left that in there when testing this. Removing it from this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this approach to changing the style on the element:-

```
littleDiv.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;'+
    'left:300px;'+
    'top:300px;'+
    'width:5px;'+
    'height:5px;'+
    'clip:rect(0pt,5px,5px,0pt);'+
    'background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)';
```

Answer (score 1):

`setAttribute` is pretty useless in IE, especially for the style attribute.
You may have to use a `class` or `element.style."propertyName"`

[quirksmode compatibility chart](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t1010)